# Is it a residential building requirement to caulk between a bathroom tile floor and a wood base?

Tags: bathroom, tile, floor, baseboard

Is it a residential building requirement to caulk between a bathroom tile floor and a wood base? I live in Snohomish County, WA.

Comment: Welcome.  Please note that as per the [faq] only national building code questions are on topic.  Local building codes vary too widely to be something we can reliably help with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about local building codes, which is off-topic

Comment: @Machavity How do you know it’s about a local Building code? The International Residential Code (IRC) is adopted in all 50 states.

Comment: @LeeSam We probably need some OP clarity then. It reads very much like it's asking for codes pertaining to Snohomish County, WA

Comment: OK, so what is the international residential building code requirement for the connection between floor tile and wood base in a bathroom?  Is caulking required?

Comment: I continue to be baffled by people who consider their bathrooms to be bathtubs themselves, as this question seems to imply. Rooms should not be depended on to contain water. That's the purpose of the bathtub and toilet.

Comment: I obviously don't consider or expect my entire bathroom to be a 'bathtub' @isherwood, but don't you think spending a little money & time on some silicon caulk to save having to rip out damaged baseboards when some water spills occur is better planning? I just wanted clarification as to whether it was a code requirement.

Comment: Caulk is more likely to cause damage by retaining water than it is to protect it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the code does not specifically require caulking between anything in a bathroom. However, it does require, “a non-absorbent floor and walls up a minimum of 6’ for tubs and showers”. (See IRC R307.2)

However, as we all know, that wood you’re concerned about will absorb moisture on the “end-grain” very easily. You should protect it with a few coats of sealer or paint to protect it...especially in a moist environment like your bathroom.

Comment: Thank you Lee Sam. I appreciate your reply.  My builder did not provide caulking protection at the wood baseboard where it met the tile floor and that just didn't make sense to me if there was ever any big water spills.

Comment: @user87174 I think just scrubbing the tile could “push” water under the base board.